# Install Legacy Version of PHP Driver for MongoDB on Amazon Linux

Tags: php, linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am attempting to install Learning Locker on an Amazon Linux site on AWS.  I have been following the [step-by-step directions on this site](http://www.jpablo128.com/how-to-install-learning-locker/), which has been helpful till now.  Unfortunately now I am stuck.

Learning Locker requires the older version of the Mongo driver (mongo.so) for PHP.  I think this is [the latest version](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.6.14).  However if I try to install the driver using pecl it will either install the new version of the driver (mongodb.so) or if I specific "pecl install mongo" I get an error that this version is depreciated.

At this point I need to:

1. Uninstall the mongodb.so driver that is installed currently.
2. Install the legacy mongo.so driver.

I have searched the Internet but I have not found what I need to know how to uninstall the existing driver and install the legacy driver.

Suggestions?  Any insight will be appreciated.  Thanks!!!

Comment: My suggestion would be to follow step-by-step instructions from an up-to-date site.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't found a better site yet but I will keep looking.  However, I'm thinking this is a standard Linux thing to do (install an older version of a driver) that is not Learning Locker specific.  I'm looking for the command line examples I need to use to install the older driver.  If someone can point me in the direction of a site that they know that shows how to install an old drive that would be a great start!

Answer (score 0):

With more research I was able to learn how to install an older driver with pecl.

```
pecl search mongo

Retrieving data...0%
.Matched packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=======================================
Package Stable/(Latest) Local
mongo   1.6.14 (stable) 1.6.14 MongoDB database driver
mongodb 1.2.8 (stable)  1.2.7  MongoDB driver for PHP

sudo pecl install mongo-1.6.14
```

This worked and I was able to run Composer to install Learning Locker.

I still need to uninstall mongodb.so but that is a work in progress.